# Proving Hermite's identity using induction

Tags: summation, induction

Can someone help me? This should be easy but I couldn't find it on any book or the internet.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor x + \frac{k}{n}\right\rfloor = \lfloor nx \rfloor
$$

Comment: It would be better if you included the actual identity for sake of clarity.

Comment: [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_cotangent_identity) and [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite's_identity) both exist.

Comment: You're right, I don't know how to use MathJax so I uploaded a picture

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor x+ \frac{k}{n}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor nx\right\rfloor$$

Question you need to ask is what should I be inducting on? Contrary to the usual perception the induction should not be on $n$ because $n$ is a "given" positive integer. The induction should be on the unique natural number $m$ for which
$$\frac{m}{n} \leq x < \frac{m+1}{n}.$$

Hopefully this will help you start the induction process.